# Limit of the product of an exponential and a periodic function

Tags: calculus, limits

The limit of the function $e^{-2t}\cos{2t}$ as $t\rightarrow\infty$ (end behavior) is $0$ (by machine).

How is it so? What is the theory behind it?

Does it create any kind of indeterminate form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Squeeze theorem may help $$-e^{-2t} \le e^{-2t} \cos 2t \le e^{-2t}.$$ Taking $t \to \infty$ shows that the LHS and RHS are approaching $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The product of a bounded function and a function that goes to zero is always zero. This is easily proved by the standard Delta Epsilon method.